# Defining the Media Query and after that giving css style to stop overflow-x but in output it takes the css style, still overflow-x scroll is visible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors, media-queries

Responsive Issues
Some of containers are overflowed horizantally in some media queries and I wanted to avoid it by
defining the Media Query and after that giving css style to stop overflow-x but in output it takes the css style, still overflow-x scroll is visible then I checked all the container to see which contianer is overflowed but no containers were overlfowed.
Main container has the max-width = 140rem;
every small container has the max-width =120rem;

[look to this photo which is the footer side of web, and you can see that a very small space appeared beside the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77VSv.png)

```
body {
  background-color: #000; 
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I used overflow-x to hidden but the whitespace in right side  still visible, which is extra

Comment: So to get answer to your query, you need to provide working code of CSS HTML. Either you just put your code snippet or create somewhere else that you can share.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what's going on, try adding `* { outline: 1px red; }` to your CSS to identify the culprit. Else produce an answerable question